# Angular minification with directive controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, minify, angularjs-controller

If I have the following:

```
myapp.directive('directivename', ...

    return {
        ...
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: MyController,
        ...
    }

    function MyController($scope, $somethingelse) {
        // Contents of controller here
    }
);
```

How do I modify this such that `MyController` will not get destroyed when minified? 
I am getting the following error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It can be resolved by using explicit dependency annotation. What you have it implicit annotation which causes issues while minification. You could use `$inject` or inline array annotation to annotate the dependencies in the directive as well.

```
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$somethingelse'];

function MyController($scope, $somethingelse) {
    // Contents of controller here
}
```

Or in the directive:

```
return {
    ...
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: ['$scope', '$somethingelse', MyController],
    ...
}
```

Or register your controller using `.controller` syntax

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$somethingelse', MyController]);
```

and set up controller name in the directive instead of the constructor.

```
return {
    ...
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'MyController',
    ...
}
```

You can also take a look at **[ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)** with which you don't need to use explicit annotation.

Comment: You know ... if only Angular gave us more options.  Why are they so inflexible?  Dang.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the following approach is used:

```
myapp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$somethingelse', function($scope, $somethingelse) {
  ...
}]);
```

to avoid such problems.

Comment: Can I do that from inside my directive? Note that MyController is one that is specific to the directive, so I put it inside of the myapp.directive(). I know that is what is "usual"

Comment: I suppose that `var MyController = function($scope, $somethingelse) {...}` 
`MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$somethingelse'];` should work.  Edit: it is similar to PSL's answer.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can use like this:

```
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: ...,
    scope: {},
    controller: ["$scope","$rootScope", function ($scope,$rootScope) {
       //code here
    }],
    link: function (scope) {
    }
}
```